# How to update the next date in specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

Below are example table of a patient visit records. It has a `Vdate` column to store the date of when a specific patient visited and a `Visit` column to show the order of the visit.

```
Table aaa
+-------+-------------------------+-------+
| ID    |  VDate                  | Visit |
+-------+-------------------------+-------+
| 10003 | 2003-09-26 00:00:00.000 |   1   |
| 10003 | 2004-05-15 00:00:00.000 |   2   |
| 10003 | 2007-01-09 00:00:00.000 |   3   |
| 10003 | 2007-07-05 00:00:00.000 |   4   |
+-------+-------------------------+-------+
```

What I want to do is to define another column `follow_up` and insert the next `Vdate` occurrence according to the `Visit` ordering.
I expected my result as following:

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| id    | visit_date | follow_up  |
+-------+------------+------------+
| 10003 | 2003-09-26 | 2004-05-15 |
| 10003 | 2004-05-15 | 2007-01-09 |
| 10003 | 2007-01-09 | 2007-07-05 |
| 10003 | 2007-07-05 | Null       |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

As you can see above, all value inside the `visit_date` column I took from `Vdate` whereas the `follow_up` column is the next `Vdate` after each visit. The last `follow_up` row shows `NULL` because the next visit (visit no. 5) hasn't occurred yet.

How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you could explain a bit more about how you get the follow up date and what exactly you are having trouble with. Are you needing the SQL query to create a new column? Or to update the follow up column for a specific row?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I have to update the follow up column for a specific rows.

Comment: No trouble. Just looking for clarification. I believe I have provided an answer that should do what you are wanting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, VDate DATETIME, VISIT INT)
INSERT INTO @Table
    VALUES (10003, '2003-09-26 00:00:00.000', 1), (10003, '2004-05-15 00:00:00.000', 2), (10003, '2007-01-09 00:00:00.000', 3), (10003, '2007-07-05 00:00:00.000', 4)


  SELECT
        T1.ID
       ,CAST(T1.VDate AS DATE) AS visit_date
       ,(SELECT TOP 1
                CAST(T2.VDate AS DATE)
            FROM @Table AS T2
            WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
            AND T2.VDate > T1.VDate)
        AS follow_up
    FROM @Table AS T1
    ORDER BY VISIT
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/QRSN87105)

If you wish to update the column

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, VDate DATETIME, follow_up DATETIME, VISIT INT)
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, VDate, VISIT)
    VALUES (10003, '2003-09-26 00:00:00.000', 1), (10003, '2004-05-15 00:00:00.000', 2), (10003, '2007-01-09 00:00:00.000', 3), (10003, '2007-07-05 00:00:00.000', 4)

UPDATE T1
SET T1.follow_up = (SELECT TOP 1
        T2.VDate
    FROM @Table T2
    WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
    AND T2.VDate > T1.VDate)
FROM @TABLE T1

SELECT
    ID
   ,CAST(VDate AS DATE) AS visit_date
   ,CAST(follow_up AS DATE) AS follow_up
FROM @Table
```

[UpdateDemo](https://rextester.com/JBO56467)

Comment: "is just a language barrier issue. And/or lack of knowledge of sql and its terminology" Perhaps he mis-tagged it, who knows? Instead of your useless and unproductive comments why don't you let the OP say what is he wanting or what is wrong with an answer

Comment: @SatishJay . . . You have tagged the question MySQL and then accepted an answer that has nothing to do with MySQL -- almost every line has bespoke syntax for SQL Server.  Mistagging your questions does not help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If using MySQL 8, which has support for window functions:

```
SELECT ID
     , VDate AS visit_date
     , lead(VDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Visit) AS follow_up
FROM aaa
ORDER BY ID, Visit;
```

should do the trick.

If using MySQL 5, maybe something like

```
SELECT ID
     , VDate AS visit_date
     , (SELECT VDate FROM aaa AS a2 WHERE a.ID = a2.ID and a.Visit + 1 = a2.Visit) AS follow_up
FROM aaa AS a
ORDER BY ID, Visit;
```

Formatting the dates is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the value already and know the `id` of the row you are wanting to update then this should set the value for you:

`UPDATE aaa SET follow_up = '2007-07-05' WHERE id = 10004;`

Note that in your example all rows have the same ID. There should be some unique id or and can add in your where clause to check for the original date you are looking for.

Comment: `ID` is presumably a patient id, not a unique row id.

Comment: That is valid. But the OP never gave how he would know what row he is looking for. Best I could provide with the current information. Will be glad to update my answer with a better solution if given the proper constraints.

Comment: The example data and results make it pretty obvious what he wants. See my answer for a couple of approaches.

Comment: He clarified in his comment he is wanting to update the database, not pull from it.

Comment: Considering his desired results have different column names, different formatting, and not all the same columns as the sample table, I suspect that OP's use of update is just a language barrier issue. And/or lack of knowledge of sql and its terminology.